# Angular Forms - What is the correct way to initialize

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a basic form that I have built with 3 fields.  Name, description and id.  The data is meant to be populated by a service that calls out to a C# API that returns JSON that is then loaded to the form.

When it opens I get the correct data but I get this error.  If I striped out the  name input, the errors just move to the description field then the id.

[image]

I am still learning Angular, but have read a heap to try and fix this.  I think I've got it all right, but I'm guessing it's something to do with initialisation because if I add this code before getting the data from the scenario service, the errors go.

```
  this.scenario = { 'id': 0,
    'name': '',
    'description': '',
    'dateCreated': '',
    'createdBy': '',
    'dateModified': '',
    'modifiedBy': '',
    'active': true };
```

So what is the correct way to code this so my interface is initialised without having to hard code it?

**test.component.html**

```
<h1>
  Edit Scenario - {{ name.value }}
</h1>
<div class='panel-body'>
<form novalidate 
      #scenarioForm="ngForm" 
      (ngSubmit)="saveForm()">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1'><label for="scenarioName" class="control-label">Name</label></div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="name.invalid && name.touched">
        <input class="form-control" 
               #name="ngModel" 
               name="scenarioName" 
               type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Scenario name" required 
               [(ngModel)]="scenario.name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1'><label for="descption">Descption</label></div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="description.invalid && description.touched">
          <textarea #description="ngModel" 
                    ngControl="description" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    rows="4" maxlength="500" 
                    placeholder="What is this scenario for?" 
                    required 
                    name="description" 
                    [(ngModel)]="scenario.description"></textarea>
           <div *ngIf="description.invalid && description.dirty" class="alert alert-danger">
              Description is required, and must be at least blah blah... 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class='panel-footer'>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <input #id type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="scenario.id" #id="ngModel">
</form>
<div id="debugging">
  <br>
  Valid? {{scenarioForm.valid}}<br>
  Model: {{ scenario | json }} <br>
  Model: {{ result | json }}<br>
  Form: {{ scenarioForm.value | json }}
  <br>
</div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule, NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ScenarioService } from './scenario.service';
import { IScenario } from './scenario';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

 @NgModule({
   imports: [
    FormsModule
   ],
   exports: [FormsModule]
 })

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scenario-form',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-inferrable-types
  private pageTitle: string = 'New Scenario';
  scenario: IScenario;
  result: IScenario;

  constructor(private _scenarioService: ScenarioService,
              private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const scenarioId = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (scenarioId) {
      this._scenarioService.getScenario(+scenarioId).subscribe(
        scenario => this.scenario = scenario);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the response from API asynchronously, you need to handle the null initially, you can do that with safe navigation operator

```
 <input #id type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="scenario?.id" #id="ngModel">
```

same applies for all your fields.

As you mentioned above, other way is to fix via initializing the object **Scenario**

Since you need to accomplish two way data binding, you need to initialize the object by creating an instance

```
scenario: IScenarioUpdate = {modifiedBy: ''}
```

Comment: I have tried this on each field one by one and get an 'Uncaught Error: Template parse error: The '?' cannot be used in the assigmemtn at column 23'?

Comment: try  <input #id type="text" name="id" [ngModel]="scenario?.id" #id="ngModel">

Comment: That works... but aren't we now only binding one way?

Comment: yes its one way binding. if you need two way databinding you should initialise the object as mentioned above

Comment: Did that help you

Comment: I went with the option to initiliase the object -  _scenario: IScenarioUpdate = {modifiedBy: ''}.  Do you want to update your answer to correct the two way binding bit and outline the other option and I'll mark as the solution?

Comment: i modified the answer